# Unexpected generic return type

Tags: java, generics

Consider these classes:

```
class ParentComponent<T> {}
class ChildComponent<T> extends ParentComponent<T> {}
class Parent<C extends ParentComponent> { C component() {return null;} }
class Child<T> extends Parent<ChildComponent<T>> {}
```

and instantiation of `Child` class:

```
Child a = new Child();
ChildComponent ac = a.component(); // COMPILE ERROR! actual type is ParentComponent

Child<?> b = new Child<>();
ChildComponent bc = b.component(); // OK

Child<Object> c = new Child<>();
ChildComponent<?> cc = c.component(); // OK
```

How does `Child<T> extends Parent<ChildComponent<T>>` became to `Child` with `ParentComponent`?

Why does java need to specify at least wild-card in order to infer the type?

Isn't `Child` equivalent to `Child<Object>` which in turn is equivalent to `Child<?>`?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321 ?

Comment: @JornVernee but how does `Child extends Parent<ChildComponent>` became to `Child` with `ParentComponent`?

Comment: Because `C` gets erased to `ParentComponent`

Comment: @JornVernee obviously, but it's weird that java is erasing parametrized-type even if I have defined that it should be at least `ChildComponent` regardless of  `T`. Btw, thanks for the link about generics.

Comment: That doesn't matter since `Parent<ChildComponent<T>>` gets erased to `Parent`.